# Rostful API - Implementation

Tags: java, android, ros

So I'm new to learning ROS and android programming, basically I have to display an info from a topic in ROS through a web request from the rostful api. and there is zero infos or documentation regarding on how to use or implement a rostful api to android and I'm hoping anyone in here could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official repository for Rostful package https://github.com/pyros-dev/rostful. Note that it is available only for ROS Kinetic and Indigo distributions. Once you follow the instructions and install rostful package, it should create an http server when run. The HTTP GET and POST requests sent to this webserver are forwarded to the roscore and the responses from roscore are sent back as HTTP response. More info on how to use the HTTP API: https://rostful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#
Any android library that provides HTTP GET and POST API should work (I think you can use android library volley).